# input form check for $_POST or $_GET array

Tags: php

```
public function get($item) {
    if (isset($_POST[$item]) && $_POST[$item] != '') {
        $_POST[$item] = filter_var($_POST[$item],FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        if(is_numeric($_POST[$item])) {
            return (int)$_POST[$item];
        }
        return $_POST[$item];
    }else if (isset($_GET[$item]) && $_GET[$item] != '') {
              $_GET[$item] = filter_var($_GET[$item],FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        if(is_numeric($_GET[$item])) {
            return (int)$_GET[$item];
        }
        return $_GET[$item];
    }
    return '';
}
```

Is there a way I can make this more efficient? And/Or can you help me improve this code? I want to check if there is value into the $_GET / $_POST array. And filter all the evil input from a bad user.

Comment: use $_REQUEST for one go

Comment: For starters: everything you do in either `if` or `else if` is exactly the same except `POST` becomes `GET` (So why not do this in another function that gets the array to use as an argument?). But POST and GET are different operations and should be used in different cases..

Comment: +1 for @kingkero
On the other hand, your code can't differenciate an empty input from an non existing input (both return an empty string)
Maybe consider using an exception? or boolean false (because standard post will return a 0 as integer for false)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_REQUEST` which contains both `POST` and `GET` variables.

```
public function get($item) {
    if (!empty($_REQUEST[$item])) {
        $_REQUEST[$item] = filter_var($_REQUEST[$item], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

        return is_numeric($_REQUEST[$item]) ? (int) $_REQUEST[$item] : $_REQUEST[$item];
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: See the edits in answer .. I have minimized the code a little ... :)